# Escape spaces in azure-pipelines.yml for the dotnet publish command

Tags: c#, azure, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I am getting the error message: "*MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified*" when the `dotnet publish` command executes in Azure Pipelines presumably because my repository have spaces in the name, but I do not have permission to change the repo name.

The section of the azure-pipelines.yml with the `dotnet publish` command:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/My App Backend/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.
    ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'publish artifacts'
```

I have tried the following to escape the spaces in the repo name, without luck:

- Replacing the spaces with %20.
- Encapsulating the filepath with "\" on the start and end.

Is there another way to escape spaces that I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Escape spaces in azure-pipelines.yml for the dotnet publish command

I could reproduce this issue on my side if I create a project with escape spaces in the name.

To resolve this issue, please try to use double quotes for the argument `--output "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"`:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/My App Backend/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"'
```

The test result:

[image]